# How to get rid of inline styles added as part of the React Native Web Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I am trying to use React Native components in the web by making use of React Native web Library.

But when doing that my DOM elements has lots of inline styles which makes it look cluttered , how can we get rid of the redundant styles as part of the transpilation .

Some thing like this

[image]

And can we even get rid of this transplied inline css.

This is how my React Native component used here looks like

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Platform, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: "Press Cmd+R to reload,\n" + "Cmd+D or shake for dev menu",
  android:
    "Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n" +
    "Shake or press menu button for dev menu",
  web: "Your browser will automatically refresh as soon as you save the file."
});

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View >
      <Text>
        Welcome to React Native Web universal app!
      </Text>
      <Text>
        This component is shared between web and react environment. To see how
        it works, just edit the HomeScreen.js
      </Text>
      <Text>{instructions}</Text>
    </View>

  );
};

/*const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});*/

export default HomeScreen;
```

After updating the RNW to 0.11.4 the DOM appears to be more cleaner and leaner but dosent eliminate them.

eg 
[image]

Comment: I have been searching for the same thing (or at least for a way to have "human readable" class names) because otherwise debugging or even finding a div is simply harder then debugging on the phone...

Comment: ya @pinturic i am hoping for some insights

Comment: @pinturic seems like using the latest version of the RNW 0.11.X fixes or eliminates some of the cluttering of css classes but dosent eliminate them